# How can I use macvtap for bridging to home wifi network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, virt-manager

I have Ubuntu 16 host machine with kvm/libvirt virtual machines.

How can I bridge the virtual machines to my host's connected wifi network (my home wifi network)?

I see people say something about macvtap since the names of interfaces in Ubuntu 16 are changed.

Please help me with this issue it's really getting on my nerves. I just want my VMs to be discoverable on the wifi network.

Thanks.